# User control of WSO2 Portal programatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to manage the WSO2 users through own portal. Following needs to be managed:

1. Create new user
2. Subscribe the user to the API
3. Get the consumer key and consumer secret to be given to user in order to generate access token

I want to do all this programmatically in a UI so there will not be any need for user to visit wso2 manually every time. I know there exists REST api's for creating user and subscribing, however, there seems to be no way of retrieving the consumer key and secret. Uploading a war file to wso2 is not an option. How can I implement the above said functionalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Store APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Store+APIs) have everything you need:

- User Signup: creates new user,
- Add a Subscription: subscribes to API,
- Generate an Application Key: generates the key and secret values for an application.

Comment: curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:80/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag -d 'action=generateApplicationKey&application=NewAPI&keytype=PRODUCTION&callbackUrl=&authorizedDomains=ALL&validityTime=360'...This is the curl command I used. My wso2 runs on port 80 and API name is NewAPI, But, this does not return any response.

Comment: For the same command above, it gives this error.......{"error" : true, "message" : "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey"}